# Reporte en Jasperreport no se ejecuta cuando llamo al archivo war

Tags: java, jasper-reports

tal vez alguien pueda darme una mano, ya que busque en google por horas y no pude dar con la respuesta. 
Hize una pequeña aplicacion Java combinando Servlets, Netbeans y Maven, cuando la corro desde netbeans el reporte se abre, pero si la despliego dentro del servidor Tomcat 9, el reporte en pdf no se abre.
En mi archivo pom.xml agregue las siguientes lineas:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>6.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Agrego el codigo donde genero el reporte:

```
 // Crea el objeto conexion, se conecta a la BD  y devuelve un objeto de tipo Connection.
    DBConexion conex = null;
    try {
        conex = new DBConexion();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw new ServletException("Sucedio un Error al Realizar la Conexion a la Base de Datos !", ex);
    }

    java.util.Date pdefec = null;
    java.util.Date phafec = null;

    try {
        pdefec = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(request.getParameter("defec"));
        phafec = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(request.getParameter("hafec"));
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MovimienController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    java.sql.Date sqldefec = new Date(pdefec.getTime());
    java.sql.Date sqlhafec = new Date(phafec.getTime());

    // se muestra en una ventana aparte para su descarga
    JasperPrint jasperPrintWindow = null;
    try {
        HashMap parametros = new HashMap();
        parametros.put("pdefec",sqldefec);
        parametros.put("phafec",sqlhafec);

        jasperPrintWindow = JasperFillManager.fillReport("C:\\JAVA\\GastosJSP\\movimientosporfecha.jasper", parametros, conex.getConexion());
    } catch (JRException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CuentaController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    JasperViewer jasperViewer = new JasperViewer(jasperPrintWindow);
    jasperViewer.setVisible(true);

    // Cierra la Conexion 
    try {
        conex.closeConexion();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw new ServletException("Sucedio un Error al Cerrar la Conexion en la Base de Datos !", ex);
    }
    return  ;
}
```

Que otra cosa me puede faltar?
gracias por adelantado!
Saludos

Comment: Incluye el código donde generas y "abres" el reporte. Tienes logs para ver si se está produciendo alguna excepción? Si no das un poco de detalles de la implementación es difícil ayudar.

Comment: En el Log se muestra alguna excepción?